# Problem with running object_detection_tutorial TypeError: load() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: tensorflow

I'm pretty new to tensorflow and I'm trying to run object_detection_tutorial. I'm getting TypeErrror and don't know how to fix it.

This is load_model function which misses 2 arguments:

tags: Set of string tags to identify the required MetaGraphDef. These should correspond to the tags used when saving the variables using the SavedModel save() API.

export_dir: Directory in which the SavedModel protocol buffer and variables to be loaded are located.

```
def load_model(model_name):
  base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
  model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
  model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=model_name, 
    origin=base_url + model_file,
    untar=True)

  model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
  model = model.signatures['serving_default']

  return model
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-9-f8a3c92a04a4>:11: load (from tensorflow.python.saved_model.loader_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This function will only be available through the v1 compatibility library as tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load or tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load. There will be a new function for importing SavedModels in Tensorflow 2.0.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e10c73a22cc9> in <module>
      1 model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
----> 2 detection_model = load_model(model_name)

<ipython-input-9-f8a3c92a04a4> in load_model(model_name)
      9   model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"
     10 
---> 11   model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
     12   model = model.signatures['serving_default']
     13 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    322               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    323               instructions)
--> 324       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    325     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(
    326         func, new_func, 'deprecated',

TypeError: load() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tags' and 'export_dir'
```

Can you help me fix this and run my first object detector :D?

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem and i'm trying to solve this for 1 week now. I guess the solution should be this;

```
model = tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load(str(model_dir), None)
```

More detail would be (from the [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load)) ;

Load a SavedModel from export_dir.

```
tf.saved_model.load(
    export_dir,
    tags=None
)
```

Aliases:

```
tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load_v2

tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load
```

Comment: I used your solution and got another error. I updated everything I could and it works! I also had an error with pathlib not being istalled.

Comment: @Dominik can you be more specific? maybe I can help because this tensorflow adventure I have led me to solve lots of issues :D

Comment: @OnurBaskin There's an error later on: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

Comment: @Dominik I assume it's your Tensorflow version. It should be version 2.0 (stable). Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689097/tensorflow-2-0-object-detection-api-demo-error-int-argument-must-be-a-string?noredirect=1#comment103676838_58689097) for the question i have asked maybe you are having the exact error. Also, search for any old import that requires 'compat.v1'. later on you should have lot's of more errors but this is how you migrate an old code.

Comment: @OnurBaskin I'm quite confused. I thought the Object Detection API was only compatible with TensorFlow 1 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I guessed it was a branch problem and using the **tf_2_1_reference** branch did the trick for me:

```
igian@iGians-MBP models % git checkout tf_2_1_reference
M   research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb
Branch 'tf_2_1_reference' set up to track remote branch 'tf_2_1_reference' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'tf_2_1_reference'
igians@iGians-MBP models % jupyter notebook
```

Then executed each jupiter cell of the tutorial like a good newbie!

This is the branch i used: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/tf_2_1_reference

Answer (score 0):

If you would just like to make a perdiction then you can also use load the model as below:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(model_dir)
```