# This load() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tags' and 'export_dir' .This is the error i get when I run the Object Detection API from Github

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I downloaded this API and used TensorFlow 1.15 as they suggested but whatever i do i keep getting this error

Here is the Code that gives me the error

```
model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
detection_model = load_model(model_name)
```

The cause of the issue seems to be the function load_model

```
def load_model(model_name):
  base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
  model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
  model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=model_name, 
    origin=base_url + model_file,
    untar=True)

  model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
  model = model.signatures['serving_default']

  return model
```

So I did try to add parameters using a solution at this page: [Problem with running object_detection_tutorial TypeError: load() missing 2 required positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683841/problem-with-running-object-detection-tutorial-typeerror-load-missing-2-requi)

As i applied the fixes (in my sparse knowledge)
Here is the code:

```
    def load_model(model_name):
      base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
      model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
      model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
        fname=model_name, 
        origin=base_url + model_file,
        untar=True)

      model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

      model = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load(str(model_dir),None)**#change i made**
      model = model.signatures['serving_default']

      return model
```

new errors kept coming up such as:

```
<ipython-input-23-e10c73a22cc9> in <module>
      1 model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
----> 2 detection_model = load_model(model_name)
```

```
<ipython-input-20-11f71129951a> in load_model(model_name)
      9   model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"
     10 
---> 11   model = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load(str(model_dir),None)
     12   model = model.signatures['serving_default']
     13
```

```
D:\Anaconda\envs\work\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    322               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    323               instructions)
--> 324       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    325     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(
    326         func, new_func, 'deprecated',

TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'export_dir'
```

Any help is appreciated ,
Thank You very much.

Comment: There is very little information to debug further. Can you show us the changes you made post which you are still seeing errors ? Did you use tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load instead of tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir)) ? If so, what is the error/exception stacktrace

Comment: No i used tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load from tensorflow documentation as i am using tensorflow1.15 i will show the changes i made . Thank you for replying.

Comment: here is the page: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a tensorflow backward compatibility issue the line `tf.saved_model.load(model_dir)`  works only in tensorflow 2.X and not tensorflow 1.X. If any one is using tensorflow 1.x freeze your graph and then tf.Session, better documentation for converting models from tf1 to tf2 available at tensorflow website : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#converting_models

Recommendation: Try To use tensorflow 2.X as much as possible its much easier to load, save and run models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :- The code works fine in tensorflow = 2.2.0 without any changes.